# karma test cases failure due to (TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined) in angular 5

Tags: javascript, angular, karma-jasmine, karma-coverage, karma-webpack

I am using karma tests to run the basic tests in my angular application.

when I try to create the test instance, it is getting the fail at indexof method which I mentioned in the below methods.

I have tried with different methods to overcome this situation still the same thing is coming up.

```js
 
ngOnInit(){
  this.init();
}

init(){
  this.route.params.subscribe(params=>{
    this.type = params['type'];
  });
}

method(type){

  if(this.type.indexOf('?') !== -1){
    subtype = this.type.substring(0, this.type.indexOf('?'));
  }
     
  else{
    subtype = this.type;
  }

}
```

```js
Test Cases:

    import { Component } from './component';

    describe('Component', () => {
      let component: Component;
      let fixture: ComponentFixture<Component>;

      beforeEach(async(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
          declarations: [ Component ]
        })
        .compileComponents();
      }));

      beforeEach(() => {
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(Component);
        component = fixture.componentInstance;
        fixture.detectChanges();
      });

      it('should create', () => {
        expect(component).toBeTruthy();
      });
    });
```

Comment: Can you provide actual test?

Comment: `if(this.type.indexOf('?' !== -1){`  <-- that is a syntax error

Comment: Why are you using `this.type`, shouldn't it just be `type` since type is passed  into the function

Comment: updated question

Comment: I don't see you providing the Router or importing the RouterTestingModule.  That must be throwing an error, since your component clearly references the Router.  Can you provide your actual code?